# NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy vs. NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

In my multithreaded app, the main thread and one or more background threads may simultaneously access, fetch, and change information in my core data store. For each thread, I am creating a new `NSManagedObjectContext`. However,  each instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` uses the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator' instance (stored elsewhere in a singleton).

My question is in regards to the merge policies of each instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`. Is there an intrinsic benefit if I set one merge policy for background threads (`NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy`) and another policy (`NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`) for the main thread?

In my `NSMangagedObjectContext` getter, I have the following conditional:

```
    if ( [NSThread isMainThread] ) {

        [_context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

    } else {

        [_context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
    }
```

Thank you.

**Edit: Is it necessary? Should I just default to one policy over the other for both types of threads?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with this solution (well over a year ago), but as I received no answer to this question recently, I decided to put my own.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context;

if ( [NSThread isMainThread] ) {

    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

} else {

    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary if you are doing save from different contexts. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdChangeManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001201

Comment: I did something like that anyway - see my answer